# Control use of class outside of extension scope?

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, extension-methods

**Quite a specific Question:** How to control the **visibility of a data class** that's used as an holder for chained extension function (in this case with infix, but doesn't matter) - either by warning or hiding.

***Easy example:*** A generic if else statement using chained infix functions:

```
infix fun<T> Boolean.gives(item: T?) : GivesOtherResult<T?> = if (this) { GivesOtherResult(item) } else GivesOtherResult(null) 
infix fun<T> GivesOtherResult<T?>.other(item: T?) : T? = this.eject ?: item
```

with a holder class:

````
data class GivesOtherResult<T>(val eject: T?)```
````

usage:

```
true gives 1 other 2
```

***Desired Behaviour:*** The `GivesOtherResult` should only be used together with the `GivesOtherResult<T?>.other` function. Outside of that function it should either be hidden or need an OptIn/show a warning

***Restrictions:*** No separate Module and no `T.other`, as `other` should only be called together with `gives` function, controlled by the use of `GivesOtherResult`. And of course usage of Kotlin

I tried creating an annotation to ask for OptIn

```
@RequiresOptIn(level = RequiresOptIn.Level.WARNING, message = "Underlying class for extension Functions. Should not be used explicitly. Opt in if used in extension function") 
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY) 
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS) 
annotation class InternalUseOnly
```

and use it for `GivesOtherResult`

```
@InternalUseOnly
data class GivesOtherResult<T>(val eject: T?)

@OptIn(InternalUseOnly::class)
infix fun<T> Boolean.gives(item: T?) : GivesOtherResult<T?> = if (this) { GivesOtherResult(item) } else GivesOtherResult(null)
@OptIn(InternalUseOnly::class)
infix fun<T> GivesOtherResult<T?>.other(item: T?) : T? = this.eject ?: item
```

but this will also ask for OptIn when using `GivesOtherResult<T?>.other` otherwhere (like
`true gives 1 other 2 //Asks for OptIn as well`
), which misses the point of this whole thing.

I cannot come up with a solution, is it even possible, does anyone have an idea?

*Btw: Reallife usage probably neglectable, but I was experimenting and now I really want to make this work*